# Drupal lost css when comment fail

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

On my node page I have the comment form that I've stylised in CSS, the problem is that when I submit this form and the form throw an error all my css disapear, I think this is my whole wrapper who disapear (a div that I set in the wrapper template is gone)

Also the comment block go to the bottom of the page, just before the footer

Here is my wrapper, for the comment I don't do something special it's just the default one

```
<div id="comments" class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
<?php if ($content['comments'] && $node->type != 'forum'): ?>
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<h2><?php print t('Avis de nos clients'); ?></h2>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php print render($content['comments']); ?>

<?php if ($content['comment_form']): ?>
  <h2 class="title comment-form"><?php print t('Add new comment'); ?></h2>
  <?php print render($content['comment_form']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

What can I do ?

Comment: which is html generated after posting comment ?

Comment: I found my solution I just add `<?php $content['comment_form']['#action'] = '';?>` in my comment wrapper template